# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I have an app and I'm getting this error message. When I run, it runs fine, but when I select an item o the navigation drawer I get the exception.
Here's my Error Log:

```
 Process: com.example.henrique.testedrawer2, PID: 26739
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams
            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.isDrawerView(DrawerLayout.java:1100)
            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.closeDrawer(DrawerLayout.java:1305)
            at com.example.henrique.testedrawerKiron.MainActivity.selectItem(MainActivity.java:133)
            at com.example.henrique.testedrawerKiron.MainActivity.access$100(MainActivity.java:26)
            at com.example.henrique.testedrawerKiron.MainActivity$DrawerItemClickListener.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:96)
            at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:305)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1146)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3053)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3860)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Here's my activity_main layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />


    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Teste"/>

        <!-- navigation drawer -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_gravity="left|start"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:divider="#eee"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's my activity_entidade layout that it's called when I click a list item(this is acctually a fragment):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.henrique.testedrawerKiron.EntidadeActivity">

   <ListView
       android:id="@+id/listaentidades"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you need to post the Code where you are playing around the LayoutParameters.

Comment: Check your imports and where you instanciate that drawerlayout.  your casting a relative layout into a drawerlayout somewhere in your activity

Answer (score 1):

I think you are closing wrong layout in your code.

Look here at my answer: [ClassCastException : java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30221418/classcastexception-java-lang-classcastexception-android-widget-linearlayoutl/30221632#30221632)

Just use your `DrawerLayout` to close himself or use `closeDrawers()` on your `DrawerLayout` object;